# Phonegap : Back button not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have created an alert to back button used in my application.

Here is what i have done

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen to the User clicking on the back button
}

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to return to Menu ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No"); 
    // Prompt the user with the choice
}

function onConfirm(button) {
    if(button==2){//If User selected No, then we just do nothing
        return;
    }else{
       window.location.replace("Menu.html");
    }
}
```

But the problem is , when i am using the back button on my phone for the first time it shows the alert but when clicking back button twice it does the same thing as back button does. It goes back to previous page rather than staying on the current page. Both the buttons(yes or no) on alert box works perfectly.

I want to remove the alert on clicking the back button twice and stay on the same page . How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have u included following js & css?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes i did . Thats why the alert on cliking back button working.